# transparent image background html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, alpha

I'm inserting an image into my canvas with this:

ctx.drawImage(myImageObject, 0, 0);

it works perfectly, except the image I insert has some parts of it as transparent and canvas seems to ignore this and it just prints what should be transparent as white pixels.

Here is the image I am inserting: http://i44.tinypic.com/25ymq.gif

I researched this problem abit and some people fixed it by doing ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data and then iterating through that array replacing pixels manually for transparency. I also read that this is bad practise because its slow (and my sprite sheets could be 1000 x 1000 and so this WOULD be very slow).

Is it possible to do something to make the transparency in my gif show up? When I saved it in photoshop and when I look at the gif itself I can see the transparency, but as soon as I stick it in a canvas it stops being transparent.

**edit**: I just tried another gif and the transparency works, but in the one above it does not, could there possibly be a problem with the above gif?

Comment: maybe try opening it up and re saving it out again.. both the source and then the actual file. have you considered png or is that to heavy in file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me with that image and the following code in the latest Firefox and Chrome beta on Mac. (Except the image itself has a few white non-transparent pixels, which you can see by opening on a dark background e.g. in Firefox.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
var canvas, ctx;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var size=500;
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(size,0);
  ctx.lineTo(size,size);
  ctx.lineTo(0,size);
  ctx.lineTo(0,0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  var img = document.getElementById("img");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
</script>


</head>


<body onload="init();">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

  <img id="img" src="test.gif" style="position:absolute; top:500px"></img>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user309641: excellent. Did you figure out what was the problem in your case? Could you share it here?